# How to use epydoc on mac to generate UML diagram for python API

Tags: macos, python-2.7, uml, epydoc

I am trying to use `epydoc` to generate UML diagrams for complex python APIs but haven't succeeded yet. I am using `epydoc` as I read somewhere that it does object introspection and source parsing.

I am using mac with python2.7 for my purposes and I was able to download and install `epydoc` from their sourceforge website.

I found documentation which was not sufficient for guy like me to be of any help, and I was not able to run commands like following as mentioned

```
epydoc --help
```

on my terminal. Can someone help me how to generate UML for python APIs using `epydoc` on mac.

How can I draw something like following which is UML Diagram for epydoc's code itself !

http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/api/epydoc.apidoc.VariableDoc-class.html

I am looking for a quick diagramming tool/utility which can help me understand and reverse engineer the python code written by other programmers quickly.

Comment: pyreverse which is now a part of pylint creates reasonable UML documents.

    pyreverse -o documentation/app pdf app_name/models.py -p app


  [1]: https://www.logilab.org/blogentry/6883
  [2]: https://www.pylint.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
epydoc --html 'name of module' --graph=all
```

This should generate documentation (along with UML diagrams), for the input module.
For further options, check out the [epydoc man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/epydoc)